# Export a report about dashboard in Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I would like to take a report about one of my dashboards and related tables, views, and materialized views. Specifically, I'd like to have report with *dashboard_name*, *graph_name*, and the *source of the graph*. Is it possible to export a report with these columns?